# ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2 login example

Tags: itfoxtec-identity-saml2

Was wondering whether there is an example of full SSO login chain ? For example, user fills in the user name and IdP will check whether user exists. TestWebAppCore and TestIdPCore seem to implement "most" of it. Which API does need to be used when I need to do user validation ? An invalid login example would help to understand the API :)

Comment: Hi @Narva, did you ever figure this out?  I am also in the same situation.  thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You are correct that the [TestIdPCore](https://github.com/ITfoxtec/ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2/tree/master/test/TestIdPCore) sample only shows the SAML 2.0 part of an IdP, it does not show user validation with e.g. username + password.
A user validation dialog can be added at this point https://github.com/ITfoxtec/ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2/blob/master/test/TestIdPCore/Controllers/AuthController.cs#L44

I use the ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2 component in [FoxIDs](https://github.com/ITfoxtec/FoxIDs) which implements a full IdP including user validation. Users and password hashes are saved in CosmosDB and the username + password validation is based on password hash validation.FoxIDs is open source and free of charge. You are wellcomme to look at the FoxIDs code, maybe it is helpful. But I have to warn you, the FoxIDs code is complex and not that easy to read.

Comment: I am trying to achieve the same Login screen as described here https://developer.okta.com/blog/2020/10/23/how-to-authenticate-with-saml-in-aspnet-core-and-csharp#try-it-out. Trying to create a complete sandbox that runs locally.  

Isn't it going to be part of TestWebAppCore ? https://github.com/ITfoxtec/ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2/blob/master/test/TestWebAppCore/Controllers/AuthController.cs#L29

@anders-revsgaard

Comment: I'm not going to add a login screen my self. You are welcome to add a pull request with a login screen to TestWebAppCore if you like.

Comment: Can you explain the differences when Login dialog is implemented on TestWebAppCore vs TestIdPCore side ?

Comment: Sorry I meant TestIdPCore in the comment not TestWebAppCore. Thank you for clarifying.